# struts2 s:if is not comparing fractional values

Tags: struts2

I am having an iterator

```
<s:iterator value="survey.questionMap" status="currentRow" >
  <s:if test="%{#key == 4.1}">...
  <s:if test="Float.parseFloat(key.toString())== 4.2">...
  <s:if test="key.equals('4.1')" >..
  <s:if test="key==4.1">..
</s:iterator>
```

All these s:if are returning false but when I prints the value of key it prints 4.1, It works fine for non fractional values like 4 etc.. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

If your `key` type is Float then you need to postfix your `4.1` with `f` to indicate that this is float.

```
<s:iterator value="survey.questionMap" status="currentRow" >
  <s:if test="#key == 4.1f">
     ...
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```